# Firebase Crashlytics IOS SourcePackages not found

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I tried setting up Firebase Crashlytics to my React Native project.
I received the following error when I was building the project after I added the build phase script.

**Script I added from the firebase guide (can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=ios#set-up-dsym-uploading)) :**

[image: Script from firebase guide]

**Error:**

> MY-APP-ABC/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run:
> No such file or directory

When I look in the folder of MY-APP-ABC, I don't see the **SourcePackages** folder anywhere.

Answer (score 13):

If you installed firebase using cocoa pods use:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

If you installed firebase using Swift Package Manager use:

```
"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I don't understand why they didn't put this in the official document.